# Why is the return function not passing the variables to the next function?

Tags: python, function, return

I'm trying to get rid of the error without moving the input function out of the userInput function. I expected the return function to remove the NameError. I looked all over stack exchange and in my textbook to figure out this problem.

```
def userInput():
    a = float(input("Enter a: "))
    b = float(input("Enter b: "))
    return (a,b)

def printFunction(a2,b2):
    print(a2)
    print(b2)

def main():
    userInput()
    printFunction(a2,b2)
    
main()
```

NameError: name 'a2' is not defined

Comment: The return values need to be *stored*.  Try: `a2, b2 = userInput()`.  Have a logical think: How does `Printfunction` know what `a2` and `b2` are, without them first being assigned somewhere?

Comment: @S3DEV I was expecting the return function would indicate that.

Comment: @StavrosPiliaris no, that isn't how `return` works at all. This is crucial to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions return *values*, not variables. The *names* `a` and `b` are only defined in `userInput`: you need to receive the values returned by `userInput` in variables defined in `main`.

```
def main():
    x, y = userInput()
    Printfunction(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the return values of `userInput` to variables if you want to be able to refer to them on the next line:

```
def main():
    a2, b2 = userInput()
    Printfunction(a2,b2)
```

or you could skip a step and pass `userInput`'s output directly to `Printfunction` as positional arguments with the `*` operator:

```
def main():
    Printfunction(*userInput())
```